# R loop for checking for NA's in two columns of a dataframe and pasting the names into a cell

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with some ID's and 6 variables. I need to check for NA's in these variables per observation, and save the label of the variable where there are NA's. I have no issue getting this to work with an ifelse() statement if there is only one of the 6 variables where there is an NA - but if there are two, I want to paste something like "OBS is missing data in *VAR1* and *VAR2*" and I cannot seem to get paste to work. Paste currently just overwrites if there is something in the new cell already, hiding the other variable where there is an NA recorded. Can you help?

Currently my ifelse statement for saving/pasting the names together (as in I want the new column to save names like e.g. "Missing_in_VAR1_VAR2") looks like this, but then, it does not work:

Within a mutate expression:

```
 colname_label =  ifelse(missing == 'Missing_in_two',
ifelse(is.na(VAR1) == TRUE, paste("VAR1"), 
                                                                    ifelse(is.na(VAR2== TRUE, paste("VAR2"),
                                                                           ifelse(is.na(VAR3) == TRUE, paste("VAR3"),
                                                                                  ifelse(is.na(VAR4) == TRUE, paste("VAR4"),
                                                                                         ifelse(is.na(VAR5) == TRUE, paste("VAR5),
                                                                                                ifelse(is.na(VAR6== TRUE, paste("VAR6"),''))))))) # NO of parentheses here is not the issue - part of a bigger expression
```

I am sorry if this question is dumb - I feel like I should be able to do this but stared myself blind on it.

Hope you can help!

Comment: `x == TRUE` is always redundant. Just write `x`. Likewise, all your `paste` calls seem redundant: `paste("VAR1")` is exactly the same as `"VAR1"`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

try `apply` with `paste`

```
dt$`missinh val in` <- apply(dt, 1 , function(x)
  {paste(colnames(dt)[is.na(x)], collapse="_")} 
)
```